# How to get rid of '[' and ']' in JSON as shown below in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I am using a function lets say `getJson()` which returns me 3 iterations every time it runs

**When loop runs just once**     //everything is great !!

```
mypayload= [{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"1",
    "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"1",
    "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"",
    "deviceName":""
}]
```

**When loop runs more than once**   //actual problem

Multiple square brackets are coming and it would be helpful if somehow i could remove the square brackets altogether **everywhere** so when loop runs multiple times i don't get an invalid json

Ideally i want that square brackets be present only at the starting and ending of the file if that is possible when multiple loops are run

**Code causing issue**

```
mypayload= [{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"1",
    "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"1",
    "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"",
    "deviceName":""
}]
[{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"1",
    "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"1",
    "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
    "description" : "sample",
    "link" : "mylink",
    "id" :"",
    "deviceName":""
}]
```

The square bracket is making this json invalid

Comment: That's not how you do it, what you do instead is start with an empty array, then append each loop's result to it so you get one big array. You do not stitch together multiple JSON outputs, you stitch together the actual data, then turn it into JSON as the last step.

Comment: can you show us the piece of code causing the issue?

Comment: Not sure I follow, what are you trying to do? Examples?

Comment: yes read it trying to understand it.. will reply also you guys should post this as answers if it works i will accept it ( i wont downvote in any scenario )

Comment: It looks like there's some code somewhere trying to append some json to some json and that code is doing it wrongly.  To help you, we need to see the flawed code.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the context. Do you have node code that inserts data into response HTML script tags? Also, this is definitely an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: No i have a AWS lambda graph function which returns json data everytime i run it...so in this scenario i am running it say 2 times so i am getting a square bracket problem... i also tried concatenating arrays but it did not work @Chris G i will try what you suggested and update you :)

Comment: If you request JSON data two times, and each time you get JSON representing an array of three objects, you need to parse first, then concatenate the arrays, not concatenate the JSON strings and try to parse invalid JSON.

Comment: @Chris G I am doing that only first parsing then concat .. but maybe i did it wrong can you specify a code snippet so i can concat the right way ?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. It sounds like that code you've written to generate the JavaScript is broken … but you haven't show it to us.

Comment: Here's a very simple example, again without knowing any relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Legqkypv/

Comment: @Chris G hey your code is not producing any output when i run it ?

Comment: The resulting array is logged to the browser's console. Press F12 to show the dev tools and check the Console tab.

Comment: @Chris G thanks alot for your help man let me try it out in the meantime you should post it as an answer i will accept it if it works cheers :)

Comment: @ChrisG hey man i want to let you know `.concat` worked and i would have accepted your answer had this not been closed

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you do not correctly add the elements of the second array to the elements of the first array.

Example:

```
let x = [{"name":"Tim"}];
let y = [{"name":"Tom"},{"name":"Fuzz"},{"name":"Buzz"}];

x.push(...y);
```

See [.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)